# Display pdf in presentation mode on a chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-os

Is there any way to display a pdf in fullscreen presentation mode on a chromebook? I have crouton installed but I want to give a presentation without boot into crouton. I found one chrome extension that almost worked, but it must not have used the gpu or something to render the pdf---it was too slow to look good during a presentation for complex pdf slides.

Answer (score 0):

The three dots button in the built-in **browser** editor has an option to Present, which brings up your PDF full screen. If you are trying to present the mentioned PDF in Gallery (that is, if you opened it in Files instead of off a PDF link within Chrome), this option doesn't show up until you select "Open in PDF editor".

Answer (score -2):

[This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/related?hl=en) PDF viewer allows for presentation mode. I believe it's the same PDF viewer used in Firefox. Be sure to let it be able to access file URLs (through `chrome://extensions`) if you are presenting a local file.

Alternatively, you can try using the default PDF viewer. Select 'Fit to page' (using the lower left button). Afterwards, you can use the left and right keys on your keyboard to navigate slides. Unfortunately, the default PDF viewer doesn't allow one to disable scrolling, but it may be worth a try.